# vendorURL.createObjectUrl is not a function

Tags: javascript

Below is a screenshot of my code:

[image: vendorURL.createObjectUrl is not a function]

Comment: 1. Paste code, not screenshot of code. 2. did you check what is in `vendorURL`?

Comment: 'use strict';

(function(){
var video=document.getElementById("video"),
 vendorURL=window.URL || window.webkitURL;

 navigator.getMedia= navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia;
      
 
 navigator.getMedia({
  video:true,
  audio:false
  },function(stream){
  video.src = vendorURL.createObjectUrl(stream);
  video.play();
  },function(error){
   //an error occured
   //error.code;
  });
 
})();

Comment: i get an error when i post a quection that way i shere screen shoot dont mine thank u

Comment: because `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just casing, try
`vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream)`

[URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)